# Codesign without xcode - error code object is not signed at all

Tags: macos, lazarus, codesign

I have a macOS .app developed in a non-xcode tool. I want to sign it, so users can download from my website.

I have manually created my "info.plist" file which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>English</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>mydemo</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>md</string>
    <key>LSApplicationCategoryType</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.company.mydemo</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>md</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string>mydemo.icns</string>
    <key>CSResourcesFileMapped</key>
    <true/>
    <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Viewer</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
            <array>
                <string>*</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeOSTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>fold</string>
                <string>disk</string>
                <string>****</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>NSHighResolutionCapable</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I have an Apple developer account and in
https://developer/apple/account/mac/certificate followed instructions for creating a Developer ID application certificate.

I am now doing this

```
codesign -s "Certificate Developer ID Company Name" mydemo.app
```

but get error

> mydemo.app: code object is not signed at all In subcomponent:
>   mydemo.app/Contents/info.plist

My .app file does noy contain in additional lib - just executable *mydemo.app/Contents/MacOS/mydemo*

I would like to successfully sign mydemo.app. I distribute my app in mydemo.zip and my goal is that when people download. unzip and drag it into /Applications it will run more easily

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `info.plist` filename should be capitalized:

```
Info.plist
```

It should codesign without issue after correcting it.

Comment: Thank you very much - everything appears to work now just as you stated it would :)